Spring Batch 3 to 5 migration: Job not launching
I am migrating Spring Batch 3 to 5.1.1, and have made the following changes in the Configuration class, after which Jobs are not launching.
Spring Batch 3:
package com;

import com.jobs.PropManager;
import org.quartz;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters.Builder;
import org.springframework,batch.core.configuration.JobRegistry;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobOperator;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashSet:
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import static com.constants.BatchConstants.GROUP;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Component
public class BatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private JobRegistry jobRegistry;

    @Autowired
    private PropManager props;

    private JobOperator operator;

    public static String FILES_BASE_LOCATION;

    @Value("$(ex.HOME:/app/data/ex/}")
    public void setFilesBaseLocation(String filesBaseLocation) {
        FILES_BASE_LOCATION = filesBaseLocation + "/";
    }

    @Autowired
    private SchedulerFactoryBean factoryBean;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        super.initialize();
    }

    @Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    }

    public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistrybeanPostProcessor(JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
        JobRegistryBeanProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor = new JobRegistryßeanPostProcessor();
        JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        return jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
    }

    public JobRegistry getJobRegistry() {
        return this.jobBegistry;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobOperator jobOperator(JobExplorer jobExplorer, JobRepository jobRepository, JobRegistry jobRegistry) {

        SimpleJobOperator jobOperator = new SimpleJobOperator();

        jobOperator.setJobExplorer(jobExplorer);
        jobOperator.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobOperator.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        jobOperator.setJobLauncher(getJobLauncher());
        this.operator = jobOperator;
        return jobOperator;
    }

    public JobOperator getOperator() {
        return operator;
    }

    public void scheduleJob(String jobName, List<String> cronExprList, Class<? extends Job> JobClass) throws Exception {
        final String METHOD_NAME = "scheduleJob";
        JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(jobName, jobName.GROUP);
        JobDetail jobDetail;
        if (factoryBean.getScheduler().checkExists(jobKey)) {
            jobDetail = factoryBean.getScheduler().getJobDetail(jobKey);
        } else {
            jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(jobClass).withIdentity(jobKey).build();
        }

        Set<Trigger> triggerSet = new HashSet<>();
        AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

        cronExprList.forEach(cronExpr -> {
            count.incrementAndGet();
            TriggerKey tk = new TriggerKey(jobName + "Trigger" + count.get(), jobName + "TriggerGrp" + count.get());

            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(tk)
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronExpr)).build();

            triggerSet.add(trigger);

        });
        factoryBean.getScheduler().scheduleJob(jobDetail, triggerSet, true);
    }
}

Spring Batch 5.1.1
package com;

import com.jobs.PropManager;
import org.quartz;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters.Builder;
import org.springframework,batch.core.configuration.JobRegistry;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.DefaultBatchConfiguration;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobOperator;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashSet:
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import static com.constants.BatchConstants.GROUP;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Component
public class BatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Autowired
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Autowired
    private PropManager props;

    private JobOperator operator;

    public static String FILES_BASE_LOCATION;

    @Value("$(ex.HOME:/app/data/ex/}")
    public void setFilesBaseLocation(String filesBaseLocation) {
        FILES_BASE_LOCATION = filesBaseLocation + "/";
    }

    @Autowired
    private SchedulerFactoryBean factoryBean;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    }

    @Override
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return this.dataSource;
    }
    
    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        return this.transactionManager;
    }
    
    public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistrybeanPostProcessor(JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
        JobRegistryBeanProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor = new JobRegistryßeanPostProcessor();
        JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        return jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
    }

    public JobRegistry getJobRegistry() {
        return jobRegistry();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobOperator jobOperator(JobExplorer jobExplorer, JobRepository jobRepository, JobRegistry jobRegistry) {

        SimpleJobOperator jobOperator = new SimpleJobOperator();

        jobOperator.setJobExplorer(jobExplorer);
        jobOperator.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobOperator.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        jobOperator.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher());
        this.operator = jobOperator;
        return jobOperator;
    }

    public JobOperator getOperator() {
        return operator;
    }

    public void scheduleJob(String jobName, List<String> cronExprList, Class<? extends Job> JobClass) throws Exception {
        final String METHOD_NAME = "scheduleJob";
        JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(jobName, jobName.GROUP);
        JobDetail jobDetail;
        if (factoryBean.getScheduler().checkExists(jobKey)) {
            jobDetail = factoryBean.getScheduler().getJobDetail(jobKey);
        } else {
            jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(jobClass).withIdentity(jobKey).build();
        }

        Set<Trigger> triggerSet = new HashSet<>();
        AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

        cronExprList.forEach(cronExpr -> {
            count.incrementAndGet();
            TriggerKey tk = new TriggerKey(jobName + "Trigger" + count.get(), jobName + "TriggerGrp" + count.get());

            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(tk)
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronExpr)).build();

            triggerSet.add(trigger);

        });
        factoryBean.getScheduler().scheduleJob(jobDetail, triggerSet, true);
    }
}

I have tried to:

Extend DefaultBatchConfiguration instead of DefaultBatchConfigurer
Remove @EnableBatchProcessing and only keep DefaultBatchConfiguraion
Autowire DataSorce and PlatformTRansactionManager

But still my Jobs are not launching.
I do not get any errors while starting the application.
